# How to immediately start the Scheduled tasks from pythonanywhere web interface

Tags: pythonanywhere

I have the web application hosted on pythonanywhere, and bash script in scheduled tasks (for daily execution).

How to immediately (manual) start the scheduled tasks from pythonanywhere web interface?

Yes, I can start the bash script from console, but I want to use the scheduled task inteface, for testing it configurations, paths, and execution log

Answer (score 1):

When you are logged into your PythonAnywhere account go to the "Tasks" page and set appropriate time. You can't start the task "immediately" though (like, say, pushing some "execute" button) since scheduled tasks are by design scheduled. So the fastest way would be to set the time +1 min.

If you want to play more with scheduled tasks in a programmatic way you might check [pythonanywhere](https://pypi.org/project/pythonanywhere/) helper scripts package. You'll find some ideas in [this blog post](https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/190/).